# How to make a drop down from excel values in tkinter?

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, combobox, dropdown

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename=r'C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Test data.xlsx' )

ws = wb['Sheet1']

range=ws['B2':'B10']

for cell in range:

    for x in cell:

        y=x.value

        print(y)

win=Tk()

clicked=StringVar()

combodata=ttk.Combobox(win, width=100,state='readonly')

combodata['values']=[(y)]

combodata.pack(pady=20)

win.mainloop()
```

I have prepared this code. This prints all values in the column but when it comes to tkinter-dropdown, it just provides the option of last value in the range provided i.e. B10 only. Can any of you please modify this code according to my need? I have more than 1000 values in the column.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think for loop will do the trick (if that helps)

Comment: What are you asking for that isn't addressed by Tkinter Lover's answer?

Comment: Please elaborate your point.@Warcupine

Comment: You say it isn't feasible, but it is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Okkkk I got it now....the code worked exactly as thought....thanxx so much @Warcupine

Comment: @OP did it work for you, or should I modify my answer? It looks like you checked it but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an empty list, then append each value in the column. Also, be sure you don't use reserved keywords as variables.

**Code:**

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# Load the xlsx file, then store the value of each column in the "elements" list
wb = load_workbook(filename=r"C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Test data.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']
xlsx_range = ws['B2':'B10']
elements = []

for cell in xlsx_range:
    for x in cell:
        y = x.value
        elements.append(y)
        print(y)


# Tkinter stuff
win = Tk()
clicked = StringVar()

combodata = ttk.Combobox(win, width=100,state='readonly', values=elements)
combodata.pack(pady=20)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Actually I have more than 1000 values in the column so it won't be a feasible option.

Comment: @KomalpreetSingh Why wont this be a feasible option if you 1000 values in column?

Comment: @KomalpreetSingh Does `elements = [[x.value for x in cell] for cell in xlsx_range]` work instead of the entire loop?

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes it works but every alternate option in drop down is shown in { } these, don't know the reason.